# Find an assignment of courses to days so that no student has more than one exam on the same day is NP-complete?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

Given a list of $N$ courses, $M$ students, the list of courses each student is taking and an integer $K$ representing the duration of the exam phase, is there an exam schedule consisting of $K$ dates so that there are no conflicts? Can you show that this problem is as difficult as the Clique-Cover problem (is $NP$-complete)?

Comment: If $K>N$ the problem is easy.

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the graph with a vertex for each course and an edge between two courses if they have a student in common. Is it $K$-colorable? (If you want to reduce from clique cover instead, put edges between courses with _disjoint_ sets of students).

Answer (score 0):

Let the courses be vertices.  Draw an edge between two if those courses have no student in common, i.e. their exams may be scheduled concurrently.  If there happens to be a $3$-clique, then all $3$ of those courses may have their exams at the same time.